# Ruby on Rails エラー対処　NoMethodError in StaticPages#home　について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

こんにちは。Ruby on rails　で学習を進めさせていただいているものですが、初質問になります。
SNS サイトのサンプルを作っています。
いつもサーバー起動の際に
`:~/workspace/sample_app (master) $ rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` を実行すると下記のエラー画面が出ます。

ヴァージョン
　Rails 4.0.5
  gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

```
NoMethodError in StaticPages#home
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `stylesheet_include_tag' for #<#<Class:0x00000002da8228>:0x007fc52c996dc8>

Extracted source (around line #5):

  <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      **<%= stylesheet_include_tag "application", media: "all",
                                             "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>**
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app
```

●custom.css.scss

```css
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;


/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}


/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $gray-medium-light;
  color: $gray-light;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-darker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

エラー文に指定された文面はみていますが、どう対処すればよいかよくわからないので
　処理の方法を教えていただければと思います。

Comment: [`stylesheet_link_tag`](http://railsdoc.com/references/stylesheet_link_tag) ではなく `stylesheet_include_tag` ですか・・・？

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= stylesheet_include_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

この部分ですが、

```
stylesheet_link_tag
```

の間違いではないでしょうか。